# Question regarding saving entity to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Lets say I have a method like:

```
 public string SetSessionData(dynamic data, string token)
 {
        var request = (data as JObject).ToObject<SetRunSessionDataRequest>();

        var session = runSessionRepository.GetRunSessionWithToken(token);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Id))
            session.Id = request.Id;
```

And then I want to save the changes in the repository class, how is that done?
will this work?

```
public string SetSessionData(dynamic data, string token)
{
     var request = (data as JObject).ToObject<SetRunSessionDataRequest>();
    
     var session = runSessionRepository.GetRunSessionWithToken(token);
    
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Id))
        session.Id = request.Id;
            
      runSessionRepository.saveSession(session);
```

Where the saveSession method in the repository class looks like this:

```
public void saveSession(session){ 
Session _session = session;
db.saveChanges();
}
```

So what I'm really asking is how do  make the save in the repository class as  I don't have a DB instance in the service class and do I even need to send the session variable? It feels pointless but if I don't how does it know what to save? Will it even save anything?

Comment: I'm assuming `db` is your DbContext in your repository, to save your `Session` object you need to call `db.Update(session);` before calling `db.SaveChanges();` so that EF Core can track the changes and save them when `SaveChanges` is called. [This article](https://enlabsoftware.com/development/how-to-build-and-deploy-a-three-layer-architecture-application-with-c-sharp-net-in-practice.html) might help explain how this pattern is implemented and help you work with the pattern

Comment: No problem, I moved my comment to an answer, I should have done that in first place. Glad I could help

Comment: I accepted it! thank you one fast question: 
 public async Task AddLatReportDataRows(LatReportDataRow entity)
        {
            db.LatReportDataRows.Add(entity);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
code like that dont need a update right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming `db` is your `DbContext` in your repository, to save your `Session` object you need to call `db.Update(session);` before calling `db.SaveChanges();` so that EF Core can track the changes and save them when SaveChanges is called.

For example:

```
public void SaveSession(session){ 
    db.Update(session);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

[This article](https://enlabsoftware.com/development/how-to-build-and-deploy-a-three-layer-architecture-application-with-c-sharp-net-in-practice.html) might help explain the pattern it looks like your code is using and why you would want to use it.